# How can I play Splitscreen in Minecraft Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I am gamer youtuber and I'm making gaming videos. I want to play with my best friend and make a video. I have a HDMI cable and a Xbox 360 HD AV cable. I've tried both of them but it still doesn't work! I've logged in a world, opened both controllers and I hit "START" but It still does not work. Can you guys help me please...